YouTube api using 100 units for search, any alternative?
I’m working on a project that ideally I need to update a list of YouTube channels and retrieve the latest video date using their channelID, however each search is using 100 units, i don’t know the videoID so cant search that endpoint. Has anyone managed to get a workaround for this? I don’t even need to embed the video, just get the date of the latest one published.
Applied for an extension but no reply, also tried the video endpoint.

The Stack Overflow answer 74579030 seems to meet your needs.

Thank you for this link, I don’t believe this endpoint contains the published or upload date for the videos inside of the returned data. If it does I guess I can store the VideoID then get the release date from that from the videos endpoint.

The YouTube Data API v3 PlaylistItems: list endpoint returns the publication dates of the returned latest videos as snippet.publishedAt.

Oo in that case! That may solve my problem. I will try that tomorrow. Thank you

Request an extension if you need more quota

I have tried to fill this in, I’m pretty new to all this and couldn’t even work out what some of the questions meant! The consensus seems to say that most people are unsuccessful with extensions

I haven't heard any issues with it the initial 10k quote is just for development.   They expect you to request a quote extension when you are in production
